# Will Steam remember my saves if I uninstall Deus Ex: HR?

Tags: steam, deus-ex-human-revolution

I couldn't run DX:HR with the graphics up all the way so I took them down a notch until I got a new computer.

Do I have to move my save files to my new computer to keep my character?

Or do they save in steam so I can play them on my new computer without saving them and moving them?

Comment: I do not think this is a DX:HR question. It is a Steam Question.

Comment: The actual files for the game are located in steam/userdata/(steamid)/28050/remote/. I would run a test with your files beforehand before trying this. Maybe find someone who has a copy of the game, stick a couple of your saved games in their folder and see if they're compatible?

Comment: The Steam Store page for DX:HR lists that it supports the Steam Cloud, but I can not determine if that includes support for the save games of DX:HR

Comment: follow up to @Xantec:
Steam is syncing something when you exit the game... but not sure if it is the save games or just setting and achievements that it is saving.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It took some time but the answer is;

Fact:
**Yes, steam will store your saves in "the cloud"** and they'll be accessible from another computer if you log in.

RANT:
That said, they'll lose your last 2 saves and you'll have to replay the last 10 minutes of play - this is because Steam is unreliable...

Fact: If you don't let steam synchronise or DX:HR crashes as you're closing it, the sync may fail as described in the rant above.

Comment: Is your last statement a fact, or just something which happened to you?

Comment: @Wipqozn - If it has happened to him, doesn't that make it a fact? :-P

Comment: It's a fact it happened to him, but not a fact that this is something that happens all the time. His last sentence sounds more like a rant then useful information.

Comment: Does this clarify it for you'll

Comment: @Coomie: It clarifies that your answer is in fact misleading, because unless I have completely misunderstood what you're getting at, it only loses any saves if steam sync actually fails for some reason (i.e. they never got synced in the first place, so they were never really "lost" from steam cloud's point of view).

Comment: @Jonathan Hobbs Steam sync failed in 100% of my tests. So while it works in theory, it isn't 100% reliable. That is what my answer stated. How is that misleading?

Answer (score 4):

One of the nice features of Steam is that it lets you install your games on more than one computer at a time.

If you can set up your new computer without tearing down your old one, install Steam and DX:HR on the new one (you'll have to eventually, after all) and see if your saved games are grabbed from the cloud.  If not, copy them over from your old computer.

[Googling for "deus ex human revolution saved games cloud"](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&q=human+revolution+saved+games+cloud) turns up a number of people having problems getting their saves into — or deleting them from — the cloud, which rather strongly implies that the normal behavior is to keep them there.

Answer (score -1):

Some games on steam have the cloud save game feature where it syncs your saved progress with your account on steam's cloud server. Deus Ex is enabled for cloud syncing so it should save it. unless something unreliable happens which it can. I recommend backing up your save files too.

Comment: Backing up your save files is a good idea. A couple of times DX:HR crashed and when I reopened it and tried to load the last save both load and continue were disabled. I fixed it by reopening DX:HR. But it scared the pants off me because I was around 50 hours in...